# Full disk encryption and data recovery capabilities

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, deletion, data-recovery

So I had linux mint with fde, had sensitive files on it, shut down my pc, and reinstalled a new linux mint OS with fde. What are the chances of data recovery from the first OS?

Comment: Even without reinstalling anything, a well-done FDE gives zero chances of data recovery.